# integration mistake

Tags: calculus

It so happened that I'd solved

$\int{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{u-u^{2/3}}}du}=-4\sqrt{1-\sqrt{u}}$

before I was to solve:

$\int{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}dx}$

I chose $u=x^2, x=\sqrt{u}, dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}du$

$\int{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}dx} = \int{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{u}-u}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}dx}= \frac{1}{2}\int{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{u-u^{2/3}}}du}= -2\sqrt{1-\sqrt{u}}=-2\sqrt{1-x}$,

which is obviously nonsense. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: $u \sqrt{u} \ne u^{2/3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since,
$$ \sqrt{\sqrt{u} - u }  \times  \sqrt{u} = \sqrt{u \, \sqrt{u} - u^2}, $$
then the mistake is where you tried multiplying together the two radicals.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest mistake was the substitution $u=x^2$. To integrate
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}dx$$
we complete the square under the radical, so that we obtain
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}}dx
=\int \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-(2x-1)^2}}dx.$$
Letting $u=2x-1$ gives us the solution $$\arcsin(2x-1)+C$$

Comment: Not to criticize, but 1) the solution my textbook gives is 2*arcsin(sqrt(x)) + C, second i wanted to figure out the mistake I was making, not the solution to the integral. More attention to the details, pleas ;)

Comment: @IlyaI.Margolin (1) I understand that you were looking for the mistake in your $u$ integral. However, I think the substitution you made is the greater mistake, and thought that addressing this is more worthwhile. (2) My solution and the textbook solution differ by a constant ($\pi/2$, I believe), and are thus equivalent.